# How can I change the direction in which a bullet moves after it has been shot?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm trying to make a bullet curve in a spiral shape.

However, I end up with the bullets freezing in place and moving in a circle instead of forward.

Here is my bullet class code:

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  #bullet class
    def __init__(self, pos, img, angle=0, speed=10, acceleration=0, curve=10):
        super().__init__()
        #import image.
        self.dir =  angle
        self.angle = (180 / math.pi) * -angle - 90
        #turns towards the mouse
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(img, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.spd = speed
        self.acl = acceleration
        self.curve = curve
        self.wave = 0
        #start lifetime of bullet
        self.born = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        
    
    def update(self):
        #destroys itself if more than 10 secs have past from birth
        self.live = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if self.live - self.born > 10000:
            bullets.remove(self)
            all_sprites_list.remove(self)
        #update stats of bullet
        self.dir += self.curve
        self.spd += self.acl
        #move the bullet
        self.pos[0] += math.cos(self.dir) * self.spd
        self.pos[1]+= math.sin(self.dir) * self.spd
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should explain your problem in a way we fully understand just by reading your question. Here we need to open external links to understand the problem. Please edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that creates spiral pathing bullets when right-clicking. Left-click generated bullets travel horizontally.

I have commented out the command to fill the frame so that you can see the path the bullet takes.

```
import pygame
import math
import random

width = 800
height = 600

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Horizontally travelling bullet"""

    def __init__(self, pos, color="grey16"):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((12, 5))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def move(self):
        """Move the bullet."""
        self.rect.x += 5

    def update(self):
        """Move and check for offscreen disposal"""
        self.move()
        # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
        if not 0 < self.rect.x < width + 12:
            # print(f"Destroying {self} {self.rect.center} X")
            self.kill()  # Remove the sprite from all sprite groups.
        elif not 0 < self.rect.y < height:
            # print(f"Destroying {self} {self.rect.center} Y")
            self.kill()


class SpiralBullet(Bullet):
    """Bullet sprite that moves in a spiral"""
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__(pos, "violetred")
        # need to track the age to determine spiral position
        self.start_tick = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.start_pos = pos
        self.angv = 0.1  # Angular Velocity
        self.v = 2.0  # Velocity

    def move(self):
        """Move in a spiral pattern"""
        dt = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_tick
        if dt > 0:
            dt = dt / 100  # slow it down
            self.rect.x = (self.v * dt) * math.cos(self.angv * dt) + self.start_pos[0]
            self.rect.y = (self.v * dt) * math.sin(self.angv * dt) + self.start_pos[1]


class Target(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill("orange")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # create at the right of the screen
        self.rect.x = width // 1.2
        self.rect.y = random.randint(50, height - 50)
        self.lives = 3

    def update(self):
        if self.lives <= 0:
            self.kill()  # Remove the sprite from all sprite groups.


# Create Groups for tracking sprites
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
targets = pygame.sprite.Group()

score = 0
screen.fill("turquoise")  # initial fill incase we disable per frame fill
done = False
while not done:
    ## Handle Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Click a mouse button to instantiate a bullet.
            if event.button == 3:  # right-click for SpiralBullet
                bullet = SpiralBullet(event.pos)
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullets.add(bullet)
            else:
                bullet = Bullet(event.pos)
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullets.add(bullet)

    ## Game State update
    # Create a target if there aren't any
    if not targets:
        target = Target()
        all_sprites_list.add(target)
        targets.add(target)
    # Call the update() method on all the sprites.
    all_sprites_list.update()

    # Check which bullets have collided with the Target.
    collided_bullets = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, targets, True, False)
    for bullet in collided_bullets:
        score += 1  # Increment the score.
        target.lives -= 1  # Decrement the lives.

    ## Draw a frame
    # screen.fill("turquoise")  # comment to see path
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    ## Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Score: {score}")
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

This will show something like:
[image: Spirals]

Here the lower orange target was created first and was hit by two spiral bullets and a horizontal bullet causing the higher target to spawn.